# How can I have group writable file permissions on apps deployed from AWS OpsWorks?

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, file-permissions, aws-opsworks

I am deploying an App (from Git) using AWS OpsWorks.  By default, OpsWorks writes the files to the server with the user: deploy, and the group: www-data.  The file permissions on these files/directories are not group writable, although it looks like they should be: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/master-chef-11.4/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb.  I was able to change the group to "opsworks" upon deployment by passing custom JSON:

```
{
  "opsworks": {
    "deploy_user":{
      "group": "opsworks"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change the permissions of the deployed files to be group writable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the permissions on the files deployed by opsworks, create a custom Chef recipe.  Example:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  app_root = "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
  execute "chmod -R g+rw #{app_root}" do
  end
end
```